# Error using CTE statements in R with RMySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, r, amazon-web-services, common-table-expression

I'm using RMySQL to run a query with a connection to a AWS MySQL database, but I'm getting the following error related to using CTE statements:

```
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  could not run statement: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE db.table
WITH CTE_1 AS (
SELECT variable
' at line 3
```

I understand that CTE statements are suported from MySQL v8.0+, however the AWS DB is v8.0.32 as well as the one installed in my system. I'm using R 4.2.2 and Rstudio 2022.12.0.

When I run the query from MySQL Workbench it works just fine, the error only occurs when using R (Ive tried both RMySQL and RMaridaBD).

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Here's an example of the SQL statement:

```
CREATE TABLE dbname.census_summary
WITH CTE_census AS (
SELECT state
      ,SUM(population) population
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN sex = "Male" THEN population ELSE 0 END) male_pop
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN sex = "Female" THEN population ELSE 0 END) female_pop
FROM dbname.census_data
GROUP BY state
),
CTE_covid AS (
SELECT state
      ,SUM(confirmed_cases) covid_cases
      ,SUM(deaths) covid_deaths
FROM dbname.covid_data
GROUP BY state
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE_census AS a
LEFT JOIN CTE_covid AS b
ON a.state = b.state
```

And this is how I'm trying to perfom the query in R:

```
library(RMySQL)
library(DBI)
library(readr)

con <- RMySQL::dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(),
                 host = "hostname",
                 user = "username",
                 password = "pass",
                 dbname = "dbname",
                 port = 3306)

query_exec <- dbGetQuery(con, statement = read_file('sql_file.sql'))
```

Comment: Can you post your full attempted SQL statement? Error message tends to truncate on problem area and suggests a `CREATE TABLE` line.

Comment: @Parfait done, I've included the SQL Statement, thanks!

Comment: As written, your query should work. See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Mnoc1WLb). Please post actual as I see different names such as CTE_1. You may be running into [reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-V) with `variable`. Or you have a syntax issue such as missing comma.

Comment: Also consider `dbExecute` for action items not `dbGetQuery` which expects a returned resultset for data frame. Also, RMySQL is no longer maintained where RMariaDB is recommended DB-API. See [Git page note](https://github.com/r-dbi/RMySQL).